# SQR - Last-Page() is printing **** when printing 1000000 pages

Tags: sqr

I am creating very simple SQR report with page numbers being printed on every page. It works fine with less number of pages. But when I tried to print 1000000 pages, it stopped printing last page number. Instead it prints `Page 1 of *****`.

Also I am not able to find any global variable which holds last page number; just like we have `#page-count` for current page.

Following code is being used to print page numbers.

```
  page-number(1,37)  'Page '
  last-page ()  ' of ' '.' ! "Page 12 of 25."
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround, create another file before it prints Asterisks. starting page number with 1 for another file.